# Can clients run a IPIP (protocol 4) tunnel inside Wireguard as in OpenVPN?

Tags: networking, wireguard

When two subnets are connected via Wireguard, clients can communicate to each other using TCP/UDP/ICMP. Can clients run IPIP (protocol 4) tunnels in Wireguard as in OpenVPN?
I'm planning to migrate from OpenVPN to Wireguard and checking if it will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run anything L3 and above (ie with IP packets) through WireGuard, including IPIP, GRE, Geneve, etc.

Comment: It works without a hassle. I've done the migration. Wireguard works via IPIP, then inside this, there is another IPIP tunnel and inside this tunnel there are IPs which are visible even in `tcpdump`.